# How to register dependencies with IList<T>

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

My class constructor has a dependency like the following

```
public EngineService(
 IList<ICommand<CalculationRequest,CalculationContext<CalculationRequest>>> commands)
```

and I have no idea how to register it correctly, any help would be helpful

Comment: More context is required to answer the question. It would be good if you provided us with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Tell us which DI Container you are using, tell us (and show us) if `ICommand<,>` implementations are open-generic or non-generic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.